# Python Printing format

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

i have a table like

This is in CSV file (which i read in python)

```
Temp   E1     E2    n
100   3000    500   0.31
200   4000    521   0.32
300   5000    522   0.33
```

I want to print follwing output in a txt file using Python

```
TableP1,101,,,,,,,100,3000,200,4000,300,5000,end.
TableP1,102,,,,,,,100,500,200,521,300,522,end
TableP1,103,,,,,,,100,0.31,200,0.32,300,0.33,end
```

Basically i have problem sorting data the follwing way and print to text file without quotes

Comment: So what have you tried so far? Your input and output don't match in any pattern that I can see, so how do you propose organizing it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question. Don't post code in comments, especially Python, where indentation is so important...

Comment: basiacally i want to print in format like sometext,,,,,Col(1)row(1),col(2)row(1),col(1)row(2),col(2)row(2),col(1)row(3),col(2)row(3),en‌​d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('1.csv') as f:
    column_count = len(next(f).split(','))
    f.seek(0)  # If there's no header
    rows = [line.strip().split(',') for line in f]

with open('2.txt', 'w') as f:
    for idx in range(1, column_count):
        n = str(100 + idx)
        r = ['TableP1', n, '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
      for row in rows:
         if len(row) < column_count:
                continue
            r.append(row[0])
            r.append(row[idx])
        r.append('end')
        print ','.join(r)
        print >>f, ','.join(r)
```

Comment: File "createtable.py", line 10, in <module>
    r.append(row[idx])
IndexError: list index out of range  (i get this error)

Comment: @EnggMechie, It seems like the original csv has a line without enough columns. I updated the answer to skip such lines. Check it out please.

Comment: TableP1,101,,,,,,,,end
TableP1,102,,,,,,,,end
TableP1,103,,,,,,,,end  >> @falsetru this is the output i get  some how table values are not appended

Comment: @EnggMechie, Could you update your question with real csv file? It seems like the csv is not separated by spaces as you posted in the question.

Comment: @EnggMechie, If the original csv separated by `,`: Change `rows = [line.split() for line in f]` with `rows = [line.strip().split(',') for line in f]`

Comment: unfortuntely i cannot post image of csv file , but input file is table i mentioned above in excelsheet

Comment: @EnggMechie, I'm not meaning you to post an image. I meant csv file as **text**.

Comment: my CSV file is a excelspreadsheet..starting from col(1)row(1).

Comment: @EnggMechie, Do you mean `.xls` / `.xlsx` file? That is not a csv file. Try save the file as a csv file.

Comment: your output looks perfect but my file is like this http://www.datafilehost.com/d/10774897

Comment: @EnggMechie, Your csv file contains only two columns.

Comment: @EnggMechie, Try this: http://pastebin.com/RqrmsvnX . I made it to work with your real csv file. (assuming no header)

Comment: updated sorry dont use that service here is dropbox link https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33370640/1.csv

Comment: works perfect thankyou very much :)  how do i skip first row.

Comment: @EnggMechie, Remove `f.seek(0)` line.